# Show label if Table View is empty

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm using Core Data to store a project name and display it in a table view. When the table view is empty (no data in the database) it is blank. From a user perspective this isn't great, so I want to be able to display a label that says "No Projects".

How would I do this? I would need to:

1. Check that the database is empty and set a BOOL
2. if this BOOL is set to true or YES, show a label? or set the cell.textLabel.text as "No Projects"

If i'm on the right tracks I'd really appreciate some example code to give me a push in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: You unaccepted, what happened?

Comment: I used a different method - About to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the following code to check if my Core Data database is empty. Works brilliantly. This must go in the CoreDataController.m file.

```
NSLog(@"Total number of rows = %d ", totalNumberOfRowsInDatabase);

    if (totalNumberOfRowsInDatabase == 0)
    {

        NSLog(@"Database is empty");
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyTable.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imageView setFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
        [self.tableView setBackgroundView:imageView];
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    }
    else 
    {
        [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }

    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   if (section == mySection) return MAX(dataCount, 1);
   else // yadda
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   // yadda

   if ([indexPath section] == mySection) {
      if (dataCount == 0) return mySpecialCell;
   }


   // yadda
}
```

Comment: By mySection I mean the section where you want this "No Projects" row to appear. Probably 0. So the if statement is just making sure you're putting the cell in the right section.

Comment: I mean it to be a symbol which represents the number of data records you have to display. If it's zero, then your database is empty. Next you will ask me what is `mySpecialCell`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a convenient lib for that: [UITableView-NXEmptyView](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/UITableView-NXEmptyView)

As easy as:

```
tableView.nxEV_emptyView = yourView
```

UPD: There's something more flexible and [up-to-date solution](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet).